# Probability that two people will be separated by r people at a circular table

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am solving the following problem:

There are $n$ people formed in a circle, two of whom are called Ana and Berta. Which
the probability that Ana and Berta are separated by $r$ people in the formation?

I don't understand how to raise the favorable cases. There is supposed to be $(n-1)!$ total cases, but I don't know anything else.

Comment: Rare probability/combinatorics problem that is more easily solved by probability than combinatorics.  Assuming that you do not have $\displaystyle \left\{~n~ \text{is even} ~~\text{and} ~~(r+1) = \frac{n}{2} ~\right\}, ~$ then you can assume that Ana is at the head of the table, and then ask yourself: of the $~(n-1)~$ possible positions of Berta, how many are satisfactory?  Also, what happens when you do have that $\displaystyle \left\{~n~ \text{is even} ~~\text{and} ~~(r+1) = \frac{n}{2} ~\right\} ~?$

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ana is in some place. Give that place the number 0, then number all the other places from 1 to n-1. Berta can sit at place r+1 n-r-1. So if r is small enough then the chance is 2 in n-1. If n is even and r =n/2 - 1 then Berta must sit in the one place opposite Ana and the probability is one in n-1. If r is larger then there are fewer than r people between them and the chances are zero.